# Placing an image in the titlebar of a firefox sidebar extension

Tags: firefox-addon

Is it possible to put a background image, and/or modify the close button (X) in the sidebar's titlebar?

I know I can set the text value of it by changing `sidebartitle=""` but is there any way to put an image in there?

Basically I'd like to put my logo up there instead of inside the sidebar where real-estate is already limited.

I'd also like to be able to do this without modifying my profile CSS so that I can deploy the changes with the extension.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up finding the element within sidebar-box with the ID of "sidebar-header" and setting that to a variable named "sbhead".

I was then able to `sbhead.style.display="none";`

Finally in my overlay.xul I added an hbox tag as a new header and set the height to 25 pixels so it would look about the same as the tabs.

Inside the hbox I added the content I wanted, to include a close button that calls `toggleSidebar()` so that the functionality of the header was the same.

I hope this is helpful to someone!